# Base of a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$a,b\in R^n$  are base of the subspace U.

is $(a+2b,b)$ a base of U?

My guess was to show that $q*a+w*b=r(a+2b)+t(b)$, but how can I show that the formal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $\{a,b\}$ is a basis for $U$, you know that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent. In order for $\{a+2b,b\}$ to be a basis for $U$, we must also have $a+2b$ and $b$ linearly independent. If this is the case, then if
$$
c_1(a+2b)+c_2(2b)=0
$$
for some scalars $c_1,c_2$, then we must have $c_1=c_2=0$ (by the definition of linear independence). We can rewrite the above equation in the form
$$
c_1a+(2c_1+2c_2)b =0.
$$
What does the fact that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent tell you about the coefficients in this last equation? Do we conclude that $a+2b$ and $2b$ are dependent or independent?

Comment: They should be independent, too.

Comment: @SuperNova Yep, absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

You check that $(a+2b,b)$ are linear independent generators:

they are genartors since they generate a basis:
$$
a= (a+2b) - 2*b\\
b=b
$$

and independent since, if you consider a linear combination
$0=m*(a+2b) + n*b= ma + (n+2m)b$ this gives you n=m=0 since $a$ and $b$ are independent.